# Merge two rows replacing nulls in pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Here's my sql

```
SELECT a."incomeNumber"  
  , (CASE WHEN b."traitName" = 'sometrait1' THEN b."traitValue" END) AS "numberResult"
  , (CASE WHEN b."traitName" = 'sometrait2' THEN b."traitValue" END) AS "dateResult"  
FROM  "request" a
JOIN "traits" b ON a.id=b."requestId"
WHERE b."traitName" = 'sometrait1'
       OR b."traitName" = 'sometrait2'
GROUP BY a."incomeNumber" 
  , b."traitName"
  , b."traitValue"
```

Result 
[image]

But I want to get one row `99 1 01.03.2018` per request, I can't сome up with solution how to deal with the trait table as `sometrait1` and `sometrait2` is the two different rows.
I'm using Postgres 9.6 and I want this solution to be plain sql if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem. I just need to remove `traitName` and `traitValue` from GROUP BY statement and adding MAX to CASE THEN.